# How to only add all files in the current directory?

Tags: git

I know `git add .` will add **files and directory** recursively to the staging tree, but I only want to add **files** in the current directory, ignoring all directories. How can I do that?

Comment: Make a list of the files-that-are-not-directories, and add them? The first part is easy enough with the right tools; unfortunately, those aren't as common as one might wish. If you are interested in files that are already tracked, or only files that are untracked, Git has `git ls-files`, which—combined with `grep`—can help.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
git add . ':!*/'
```

`':!*/'` excludes directories.

Comment: Can you say more about how that works? I've never seen anything after the dot.

Comment: @matt Sorry, I don't remember where it's documented. `:!` excludes the following path.

Comment: @matt It's mentioned in the release note, https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.0.txt#L121

Comment: Clever, and definitely the way to go for this particular problem.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec

Comment: @phd correct-a-mundo and extremely eye-opening for some of us

Comment: @matt Strange place for an important bit of docs but well… here it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to `find` out only files, and pass the list to `git add`, for example

```sh
git add $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```